# Unable to Update the Entity having unidirectional one to many with shared primary key and composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate/JPA and having below relationship in between Hibernate classes.

MediaRequestDetails <-> Disclosure(one to one with shared primary key)
Disclosure <-> DisclosureAuthor(one to many)

Below are the class definations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_REQUEST_DETAILS")
public class MediaRequestDetails implements WFPayload , Serializable{

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name="REQUEST_ID_SEQ", sequenceName="REQUEST_ID_DBSEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "REQUEST_ID_SEQ")
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        Long requestId;//id of the request

         @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "mediaRequDetails")
    DisclosureDetails disclosureDetails;
}
```

Disclosure Details class defination

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AW_DISC_DETAILS")
public class DisclosureDetails implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id 
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID")
    Long requestId;


    @Column(name="DISC_LANG")
    String discLanguage;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName="REQUEST_ID")
    Set<DisclosureAuthor> reqDiscAuthorsSet;

    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID")
    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @MapsId
    private MediaRequestDetails mediaRequDetails;

   //getter setter methods are here

   @PrePersist
public void prePersistCallBack(){
    if(reqDiscAuthorsSet!=null && reqDiscAuthorsSet.size() >0){
        for(DisclosureAuthor discAuthor:reqDiscAuthorsSet){

            DisclosureAuthorPK dpk=discAuthor.getPk();
            dpk.setRequestId(mediaRequDetails.requestId);
        }
    }
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdateCallBack(){
    if(reqDiscAuthorsSet!=null && reqDiscAuthorsSet.size() >0){
        for(DisclosureAuthor discAuthor:reqDiscAuthorsSet){

            DisclosureAuthorPK dpk=discAuthor.getPk();
            dpk.setRequestId(mediaRequDetails.requestId);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((requestId == null) ? 0 : requestId.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    DisclosureDetails other = (DisclosureDetails) obj;
    if (requestId == null) {
        if (other.requestId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!requestId.equals(other.requestId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

Disclosure Author class defination

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AW_DISC_AUTHOR")
public class DisclosureAuthor implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @EmbeddedId
    private DisclosureAuthorPK pk;

  //getter and setter methods goes here

    /* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((pk == null) ? 0 : pk.hashCode());
    return result;
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    DisclosureAuthor other = (DisclosureAuthor) obj;
    if (pk == null) {
        if (other.pk != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!pk.equals(other.pk))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

DisclosureAuthorPK

```
@Embeddable
public class DisclosureAuthorPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long requestId;
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long authorsId

        @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((authorsId == null) ? 0 : authorsId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((requestId == null) ? 0 : requestId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DisclosureAuthorPK other = (DisclosureAuthorPK) obj;
        if (authorsId == null) {
            if (other.authorsId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!authorsId.equals(other.authorsId))
            return false;
        if (requestId == null) {
            if (other.requestId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!requestId.equals(other.requestId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am trying to update the mediarequestDetails with the below program. The requestId 187 has already three author associated with it in the database.
But in the below program I am just adding the one author in the set and rest of the two author must be deleted from the database that is my expectation.

```
public class TestDisclosureSample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("rawsjpa").createEntityManager();
       //prepare mediarequest object
       MediaRequestDetails obj=new MediaRequestDetails();
       obj.setRequestId(187L);
        obj.setRequestType("MDA");

       //prepare disclosure details
       DisclosureDetails discDetails=new DisclosureDetails();
        discDetails.setRequestId(187L);
        discDetails.setDiscLanguage("English");
        discDetails.setMediaRequDetails(obj);
        obj.setDisclosureDetails(discDetails);       

      DisclosureAuthor dscauthor1=new DisclosureAuthor();
        DisclosureAuthorPK pk1 = new DisclosureAuthorPK();
        pk1.setAuthorsId(1237L);
        pk1.setRequestId(187L);
        dscauthor1.setPk(pk1);
        //dscauthor1.setMediaRequDetails(obj);
        discAuthorSet.add(dscauthor1);

     Session session =(Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
        if(entityManager!=null){
            System.out.println("************* EntityManager is obtained for Updation*****************");
            Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();

            session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
            tx.commit();
        }   

        session.close();

  }
}
```

When I am executing the above program I am getting the below output with exception.

```
Hibernate: select disclosure_.AUTHOR_ID, disclosure_.REQUEST_ID from AW_DISC_AUTHOR disclosure_ where disclosure_.AUTHOR_ID=? and disclosure_.REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: select disclosure_.AUTHOR_ID, disclosure_.REQUEST_ID from AW_DISC_AUTHOR disclosure_ where disclosure_.AUTHOR_ID=? and disclosure_.REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_REQUEST_DETAILS set ANALYST_ATTESTATION=?, ANALYST_DERV_POS=?, ANALYST_DISCLOSURE=?, ANALYST_POS_DETAILS=?, CA_COMMENT=?, CORP_AFFAIRS_OWNER=?, CORP_AFFAIRS_REGION=?, REQ_CREATE_DATE=?, REQ_CREATED_BY=?, IS_EVENT_CAN_OR_POST=?, EVENT_DATETIME=?, EVENT_TIME_ZONE=?, EVENT_TYPE_ID=?, IS_ANALYST_ATTESTATION=?, IS_APPRVL_BY_CORP=?, IS_APPRVL_BY_LEGAL=?, IS_BYPASS_DISCL=?, LAST_MODIFIED_BY=?, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE=?, LEGAL_COMMENT=?, IS_LOCATION_USA=?, PRINTED_MTRL=?, PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=?, RSN_EVENT_CAN_OR_POST=?, REQ_COMP_NOT_FOUND=?, REQUEST_STATUS=?, REQUEST_TYPE=?, REQUESTOR=?, REQUESTOR_REGION=?, REQUESTOR_TYPE=?, SUBMIT_COMMENT=?, TASKREADY_ID=?, TASKREADY_NAME=? where ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_DISC_DETAILS set DISC_LANG=? where REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_REQUEST_DETAILS_COMPANIES set REQUEST_ID=null where REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_REQUEST_DETAILS_COMPANIES set REQUEST_ID=null where REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_REQUEST_DETAILS_COUNTRIES set REQUEST_ID=null where REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_REQUEST_DETAILS_COUNTRIES set REQUEST_ID=null where REQUEST_ID=?
Hibernate: update AW_DISC_AUTHOR set REQUEST_ID=null where REQUEST_ID=?
Aug 14, 2015 5:06:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1407, SQLState: 72000
Aug 14, 2015 5:06:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01407: cannot update ("AW"."AW_DISC_AUTHOR"."REQUEST_ID") to NULL

Aug 14, 2015 5:06:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect$2.convert(Oracle8iDialect.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.remove(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1157)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRemoveAction.execute(CollectionRemoveAction.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at com.cira.raws.mediawf.bean.TestDisclosureSample.saveMediaRequestDetailsWithDisc(TestDisclosureSample.java:64)
    at com.cira.raws.mediawf.bean.TestDisclosureSample.main(TestDisclosureSample.java:46)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update ("AW"."AW_DISC_AUTHOR"."REQUEST_ID") to NULL

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
    ... 14 more
```

Apology for the length of the question but I have only provided the details needed to identify the root cause Can any body please tell me what I am doing wrong in the above mapping?

Comment: I would suggest you change the DisclosureDetails->DisclosureAuthor mapping, as it appears there are two ways to set the DisclosureAuthor's REQUEST_ID field - through the embeddable mapping and through the 1:M relationship from the DisclosureDetails side.  Dereferencing the entity will cause it to be deleted, but the ordering of statements is provider dependent and the provider has no way of knowing the DisclosureDetails->DisclosureAuthor relationship's FK is the ID as well.    The code using the discAuthorSet collection is missing in the code example

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the prompt reply. But I am not good much in hibernate .If you can please explain in more simpler terms or if you can make changes in my code and reply it will also do.

Comment: I thought you would have had the code already, since you have commented out a dscauthor1.setMediaRequDetails(obj); call that was likely to set the backpointer.  I am suggesting you setup the DisclosureDetails-DisclosureAuthor relation the similar to how you have the MediaRequestDetails-DisclosureDetails relation.

Comment: @Chris. Thanks for the reply. But I thought of making the relationship between the DisclosureDetails and DisclosureAuthor as the unidirectional by adding the statement @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName="REQUEST_ID")
    Set<DisclosureAuthor> reqDiscAuthorsSet; I dont understand why hibernate is not picking up the primary foreign key relationship between the REQUEST_ID columns of  two tables.Do I need to make the relationship between the DisclosureDetails->DisclosureAuthor bidirectional compulsory?

Comment: In Unidirectional OneToMany, the join column specifies that the target field in the referenced table is controlled by the primary key in this entity.  The "foreign key" though is that tables primary key and already set by the pk.requestID mapping, so it has two mappings to it which is a problem.  It should only be writable by one of the mapping; I suggested you make it bidirectional so you could use the mapsID on it, but you could just make the OneToMany insertable+updatable =false.  This might be why you are getting the exception, but I can't say for sure.